# Reading chunks of bytes from an InputStream

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, buffer, inputstream

In my application I'am receiving a byte stream via Bluetooth.
I am using `DataInputStream` to read a fixed amount of bytes at once from an input stream:

```
private final InputStream mInStream = ...
...
DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(mInStream);
...
while(true) {
... = dataInputStream.readFully(buffer,0,length);
}
```

Can i improve performance by wrapping mInStream in a `BufferedInputStream` and put this `BufferedInputStream` into `DataInputStream`?
E.g.:

```
private final InputStream mInStream = ...
...
BufferedInputStream buffInStream = new BufferedInputStream(mInStream);
DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(buffInStream);
...
while(true) {
... = dataInputStream.readFully(buffer,0,length);
}
```

Will this gain performance? Or will it stay the same since i am reading a constant number of bytes from the inputstream?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Can i improve performance by wrapping mInStream in a BufferedInputStream and put this BufferedInputStream into DataInputStream?

It depends on how large the buffer you're reading into is. The default internal buffer of a `BufferedInputStream` is 8k bytes. If your own buffer is comparable to or larger than this, there is no advantage. If your buffer is say 128 or 256 bytes there almost certainly is.

```
... = dataInputStream.readFully(buffer,0,length);
```

`readFully()` doesn't return a value. You should only use this method when you're sure that you want exactly this many bytes, and that they should all be present in the input. If the remaining input is shorter than `'length` it will throw `EOFException` and you will lose any data that has been partially read. If you're not sure how much data should be read you should use `read(byte[])` or `read(byte[], int, int).`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need readFully because i need to parse commands of a fixed length out of the byte stream. Each data frame which I read via readFully has a length of at most 128 Bytes. So as I understand this correctly, I should create my buffer with length 128 (because that's the max command length)? And it will be a good size in order to gain performance with BufferedInputStrams?

Comment: I think you should use a `BufferedInputStream` in this case, yes. But I'm concerned about 'at most 128 bytes' and 'max command length'. You need to use a buffer of *exactly* the expected length, or provide a `length` parameter of the appropriate value in each case. If you always read 128 bytes you will always get 128 bytes, even if the command can be shorter, which is what 'at most' implies.

Comment: Ok I think this will be no problem. Because it's like that: Before I start data transmission I know the length of the commands that will be sent. Like, Ok in the next data stream I'll receive commands all of the length x. So I create my buffer with length x. And start reading. So the length will not change with each data frame. When I reconfigure the application I simply recreate the buffer array with another length which equals the lenght of the new commands to receive and start reading again.